# AWS ASP.NET Core 2.1 and CORS with angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, cors

this is just anothor CORS problem. The setting is a AWS Lambda function written in ASP.NET Core 2.1. At the ASP.NET Core backend CORS is enabled:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     ...
     options.AddPolicy("DeveloperCors", builder =>
     {
         builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
     }
     ...
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider  actionDescriptorProvider)
 {
     ...
     app.UseCors("DeveloperCors");
     ...
 }
```

The client application queries with Angulars common/http and with a bearer token in the Authentication header.

The first request to the server is a OPTIONS Request with these headers:

```
Accept:                             */*
Accept-Encoding                     gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language                     de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-Headers:     authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:      POST
Connection:                         keep-alive
Host:                               devperts-test2.d-velop.cloud
Origin:                             http://localhost:4200
Referer:                            http://localhost:4200/
TE:                                 Trailers
User-Agent:                         Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0
```

And the answer is:

```
access-control-allow-credentials:   true
access-control-allow-headers:       authorization,content-type
access-control-allow-origin:        http://localhost:4200
content-security-policy:            frame-ancestors 'self'
date:                               Mon, 12 Oct 2020 09:58:56 GMT
server:                             openresty/1.15.8.3
vary:                               Origin
x-amz-apigw-id:                     XXXXX
x-amzn-requestid:                   XXXXX
x-amzn-trace-id:                    XXXXX
X-Firefox-Spdy:                     h2
x-frame-options:                    SAMEORIGIN
```

At the AWS log I see the response is from my application. Then the client sends a POST request:

```
Accept:                             application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:                    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:                    de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Authorization:                      Bearer XXXXX
Connection:                         keep-alive
Content-Length:                     212
Content-Type:                       application/json
Host:                               devperts-test2.d-velop.cloud
Origin:                             http://localhost:4200
Referer:                            http://localhost:4200/
TE:                                 Trailers
User-Agent:                         Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0
```

And the server answers:

```
content-encoding:                   gzip
content-security-policy:            frame-ancestors 'self'
content-type:                       text/plain
date:                               Mon, 12 Oct 2020 09:58:56 GMT
server:                             openresty/1.15.8.3
vary:                               Accept-Encoding
X-Firefox-Spdy:                     h2
x-frame-options:                    SAMEORIGIN
```

This response is generated from the AWS API Gateway because there is no entry at the CloudWatch log. At the console window of my browser I see, the following messages:

```
Cross-source (cross-origin) request blocked: The same source rule prohibits reading the external resource on https://devperts-test2.d-velop.cloud/XXXX. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing).
```

This is translated from german by deepl.

There are serveral tips like activating cors at AWS function, but nothing worked.

Slowly I think I am too stupid for this. Maybe someone else here has a tip for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
 builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin();
```

try this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first it didn't work at all with it (also no GET-requests). After I removed the withCredentials in the client (Angular) at the TokenInterceptor the GET-requests worked again. Unfortunately I still have the same behavior with POST requests.

Comment: You must allow the Client IP address from AWS

Comment: At the API Gateway I enabled CORS and Deployed the API. The Gateway Responses for Default 4XX and the most others are configured "Access-Control-Allow-Origin = '*', Access-Control-Allow-Methods = 'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT' and Access-Control-Allow-Headers = 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'. Did you mean this?

Comment: @MehmetCeylan I'm not votiing to close this because it led the user to find the answer. But it needs more explanation, not just "try this". Even a complete sentence would help.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know about AWS. I just guessed. because there is no problem in the code